# How to process standard input NodeJS, in the console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to write NodeJS code for solving problems like ICPC. The following is an example using a template of www.hackerrank.com for submitting in JavaScript:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');

var input_stdin = "";
var input_stdin_array = "";
var input_currentline = 0;
process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
    input_stdin += data;
});
process.stdin.on('end', function () {
    input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split("\n");
    main();    
});
function readLine() {
    return input_stdin_array[input_currentline++];
}
/////////////// ignore above this line ////////////////////
function main() {
    var s = readLine();
    s = s.split(",");
    s = s.join(" ");
    process.stdout.write(s);
}
```

I want to code offline, so I need to run the programs in my Windows console. For runnig the srcript using *C:users\user>node path\file.js* I added at the end of the code the line

```
main();
```

and the scripts runs, but it doesn't process the standard input. It gives me and error in "s=s.split()", the error is the following *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"*. If anyone know how to do *node* process the standard input please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wait for `SIGINT`, The `SIGINT` event is emitted whenever the input stream receives a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> input, known typically as `SIGINT`. If there are no `SIGINT` event listeners registered when the input stream receives a `SIGINT`, the pause event will be emitted.

When `SIGINT` is received, your `main()` function will be called and after returning, The `process.exit()` will close the process.

So instead of waiting for end event

```
process.stdin.on('end', function(){
    input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split("\n");
    main();
});
```

You can wait for 'SIGINT' as below:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function(){
    input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split("\n");
    main();
    process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you modify your code to append to an array with each line rather than creating one long string and then splitting it. e.g.

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');

var input_stdin_array = [];
var input_currentline = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
    input_stdin_array.push(data);
});

process.stdin.on('end', function () {
    main();    
});

function readLine() {
    if (input_currentline >= input_stdin_array.length) {
        return "";
    }

    return input_stdin_array[input_currentline++];
}

/////////////// ignore above this line ////////////////////
function main() {

    do
    {
        var line = readLine();
        console.log("Line: " + line)
    } while ((line||"") !== "")
}
```

In addition, as the other answer says, you want to listen to 'SIGINT' rather than 'end'.

I'd also suggest using the Readline module, like so:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var reader = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: true
});

var lines = [];

reader.on('line', function (line) {
    lines.push(line);
});

reader.on('close', function (line) {
    console.log('All done:');
    console.log('Lines: ', lines);
});
```

You can trigger 'close' using CTRL-D.

Answer (score 2):

- First to run this code save the file at any location with .js extension.
- using Command Prompt, go to that folder.
- run the script using node js

  node file.js
- then start typing your input on the console.
- once done hit Cntrl+C and the code written in the *SIGINT* process are executed.
- have made the following changes in the code

  ```
  process.stdin.resume();
  process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');

  var input_stdin = "";
  var input_stdin_array = "";
  var input_currentline = 0;

  process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
     input_stdin += data;
  });

  process.stdin.on('end', function () {
    input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split("\n");
    main();    
   });

  process.on('SIGINT', function(){
     input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split("\n");
     main();
     process.exit();
  });

  function readLine() {
    return input_stdin_array[input_currentline++];
  }
  /////////////// ignore above this line ////////////////////
  function main() {
    var s = readLine();
    s = s.split(",");
    s = s.join(" ");
    process.stdout.write(s);
  }
  ```